# In Meteor, how can I create a new Mongo collection from within an event handler?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to figure out how to add a new collection each time a button is pressed. I have this html:

html:

```
<template name="tempName">
    <button class="submitButton">Submit</button>
</template>
```

javascript:

```
Template.tempName.events({
    'click .submitButton': function() {
      count += 1;
      Npm.newCol = new Mongo.Collection("NUM:" + count);
      Npm.newCol.insert({
        field1: "field1 contents",
        field2: "field2 contents"
      });
    }
  });
```

This does absolutely nothing, as far as I can tell. If I put all the contents from the .submitButton click event at the top of the js file (outside of the "if (Meteor.isClient)"), then it works perfectly. But I would like a new collection to be created each time a form is submitted. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you looking to insert a new document into an existing collection? Dynamically created collections are almost never the correct solution to any problem in meteor.

Comment: Unfortunately, each form submission will automatically generate as many as hundreds of new documents within a collection, and I need them to be separate-- I can't have all the documents from various runs all in the same collection. So perhaps it's bad, but I'm pretty sure dynamically created collections is the correct solution in my case.

Comment: Well, you can create unmanaged client collections pretty easily, but creating a new collection that the server knows about is actually [really tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214667/creating-new-meteor-collections-on-the-fly).

Comment: Oh dang. I hadn't seen that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy enough, just call a method that has access to the server so it creates the local collection and the Mongo collection.

That said, if you're allowing users to create collections, I'm 99% sure you're gonna have a bad time...

Comment: Alright, thanks. That makes sense. And no worries, allowing users to create collections won't be a problem in my specific situation.

Comment: Actually question: what do you mean by "method that has access to the server"? Is this something more than just a method in the Meteor.methods section?

Comment: Ah, good question. I just meant that the code should be somewhere other than the `client` or `server` folder

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for clarifying